# VUEJS and CKEditor: Customize toolbar in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, ckeditor

I have VUEJS app and I use CKEditor, I want to add color buttons on the toolbar, but it is not working.

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
Vue.use(CKEditor);

<ckeditor :editor="editor" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>

editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorData: "<p>Content of the editor.</p>",
      editorConfig: {
        toolbarGroups: [
          { name: "document", groups: ["mode", "document", "doctools"] },
          { name: "clipboard", groups: ["clipboard", "undo"] },
          {
            name: "editing",
            groups: ["find", "selection", "spellchecker", "editing"]
          },
          { name: "forms", groups: ["forms"] },
          "/",
          { name: "basicstyles", groups: ["basicstyles", "cleanup"] },
          {
            name: "paragraph",
            groups: ["list", "indent", "blocks", "align", "bidi", "paragraph"]
          },
          { name: "links", groups: ["links"] },
          { name: "insert", groups: ["insert"] },
          "/",
          { name: "styles", groups: ["styles"] },
          { name: "colors", groups: ["colors"] },
          { name: "tools", groups: ["tools"] },
          { name: "others", groups: ["others"] },
          { name: "about", groups: ["about"] }
        ]
      },
```

But in the final, I have got a toolbar that does not have the buttons that I put.

Comment: It looks like you've used CKEditor5's Vue integration with toolbar settings for CKEditor4. Note that these are two different editors and toolbar for CKEditor4 won't work for CKEdior5.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i set custom toolbar for ckeditor in vuejs ?
witch version have I to use for setting custom toolbar ?

Comment: Docs for the toolbar for the CKEditor5 are available here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html. Note that these toolbar items might require some additional plugins loaded which might implicate need of creating a custom build. All should be described here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html

Comment: sorry I did not understand the documentation, can you explain me how to add "color texte" for exemple ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but all the steps are explained in docs. I can't explain it more.

Comment: @AmineHaroun i am having the same issue. could you please help if you solved this ?